# Convert string to float or double

Tags: smart-contract, c++, float-point

I am trying to convert a string to a float or double, however none of the standard C/C++ methods seem to work. I have tried:

```
atof
strtof
strtod
sscanf
```

In each case, I get an error message when trying to do `cleos set contract...` along the lines of:

```
Error 3070000: WASM Exception
Error Details:
env.strtod unresolveable
pending console output:
```

Is there a way to convert a string to a float or double that I can use?

Comment: Can't try it out right now, but perhaps you can use [`eosio::string_to_name()`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/9be89106da1d6a1543eb19dd0f3b96a53e286088/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/name.hpp#L21) to convert a string to `uin64_t` and then convert that to float either using `(float)` cast or `static_cast<float>`. Note that if your `string` is `std::string` you'd need to pass `eosio::string_to_name(your_string.c_str())`

Comment: I considered that, but to the best of my knowledge `eosio::string_to_name()` converts `char`s to their binary representation and then sticks that into the uint64_t. So although it does give a number, the number would just be the combination of the ASCII codes from the string. Additionally it wouldn't be able to deal with decimal points, or negative numbers that start with the minus symbol.

Comment: When will you need to convert a string to float? I don't think there's any place need to do this.

Comment: Lets say I want to parse a number in the memo of a transaction, and the number could be a float.

Comment: This problem is still not fixed @Qiang Fang

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem.  I discovered that `atoi()` actually works (nothing else did).  so I wrote it like this:

```
float token::stof(std::string s, float def)
{   
    if (s == "") return def;
    std::size_t i = s.find(".");
    int digits = s.length() - i - 1;
    s.erase(i, 1); 
    return atoi(s.c_str()) / pow(10, digits);
}
```

Comment: This would remove the decimal places from the float, would it not?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  the procedure maintains the value i.e. "3.25" becomes 3.25

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help

```
double stringtodouble(string str)
{
 double dTmp = 0.0;
 int iLen = str.length();
 int iPos = str.find(".");
 string strIntege = str.substr(0,iPos);
 string strDecimal = str.substr(iPos + 1,iLen - iPos - 1 );
 for (int i = 0; i < iPos;i++)
 {
  if (strIntege[i] >= '0' && strIntege[i] <= '9')
  {
   dTmp = dTmp * 10 + strIntege[i] - '0';
  }
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < strDecimal.length(); j++)
 {
  if (strDecimal[j] >= '0' && strDecimal[j] <= '9')
  {
   dTmp += (strDecimal[j] - '0') * pow(10.0,(0 - j - 1));
  }
 }
 return dTmp;
}
```

Comment: you can add the signed number support, for example: -10.123